# Implementing Binary tree without using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, oop, binary-tree

I am trying to implement binary tree in C++ without using pointers.

```
class node{
    public:
    int val;
    node left;
    node right;
};
```

This gives

```
error: field ‘left’ has incomplete type ‘node’
```

However, if I write this

```
class node{
    public:
    int value;
    vector<node> children;
};
```

The code compiles just fine.

What is wrong with the first approach?

Also, why do most of the implementations that I see in C++ for binary trees use pointers?
Is it not a good idea to avoid pointers and the associated bugs/complexity?

Comment: You can't create your node like the first example. Think of how large the node would be if each node contained 2 other nodes. Answer: it would be infinitely large because each of the left and right nodes would contain 2 nodes ... with no way to break the cycle.

Comment: `vector<node> children;` works because it uses pointers, not for `node` but for the storage of the `vector`.

Comment: ***Is it not a good idea to avoid pointers and the associated bugs/complexity?*** You could use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` which removes the worry about memory management.

Comment: @drescherjm in that case a  `unique_ptr` would most certainly be better.